# I can't access .js but it work well in browser

Tags: javascript, authorization

I use above script to show popup when visitors click anywhere in website. When I access link: http://yllix.com/popup.php?section=General&pub=766137&ga=g&show=2, it showed:

```
document.write('
Un-authorized access!

Yllix media
');
```

Can you explain me how it work, please ? Why I can't access link ? What method they use ?

Comment: Did you add this as a script, or is it in the HTML? Can you provide the raw code you are using

Comment: @LouBichard, Hi, It work with any HTML.